# Conditional Default-Value in Azure Pipeline DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I use Azure Pipelines to Build my solution. When building manually the user can decide which Build Configuration to use. Now I want the default value (and so the value when triggered automatically) to be different according to the branch. This is my (non-working) approach:

```
name:   PR-$(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
  - develop
  - test 
  - master
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
parameters:
- name: BuildConfiguration
  displayName: Build Configuration
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
  default: Debug
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test') }}:
  default: Release
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
  default: Release
  values:
  - Debug
  - Release
```

The conditional part (`${{...}`) simply does not work. (*`"A template expression is not allowed in this context"`)

Is there any other approach to make this happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible to use expressions to select default value for parameters.

Parameters also can't be optional:

> Parameters must contain a name and data type. Parameters cannot be optional. A default value needs to be assigned in your YAML file or when you run your pipeline. If you do not assign a default value or set default to false, the first available value will be used.

What you can do is use parameters and variables:

```yaml
name:   PR-$(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
  - develop
  - test 
  - master
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
parameters:
- name: BuildConfiguration
  displayName: Build Configuration
  default: Default
  values:
  - Debug
  - Release
  - Default

variables:
- name: buildConfiguration
  ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(parameters.BuildConfiguration, 'Default')) }}:
    value: Debug
  ${{ elseif and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test'), eq(parameters.BuildConfiguration, 'Default')) }}:
    value: Release
  ${{ elseif and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), eq(parameters.BuildConfiguration, 'Default')) }}:
    value: Release
  ${{ else }}:
    value: ${{parameters.BuildConfiguration}}


steps:
- script: |
    echo $(buildConfiguration)
    echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

Comment: "If you do not assign a default value or set default to false, the first available value will be used"
can you elaborate? Setting `default: false` or omitting doesn't pick the first `values:` as I understand this sentence

Comment: This comes from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script). My understanding is the same, but it's clearly not true.